# Popup Dialog In Angular 4 with table inside

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I want to open one popup on click of information icon (or anything).
Popup will contain table, text box etc.
Here how to pass id on click of that icon and other side how to use that id on oninit to get the values from webapi to load in table.

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: I am asking idea , how to start with..

Comment: Here's the guideline on how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: checkout https://medium.com/@ladyleet/popups-modals-and-navigation-using-angular-material-2-components-in-your-angular-2-project-faf510dbcdee link; they have mention step by step how to include modal popup ; also mention how to pass data to modal using service

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this. Assuming you have data to loop over in your HTML file.

```
<div*ngFor="let data of sampledata; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
               <span class="viewIcon" (click)="openPopup(i)"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
```

In your .ts file also assuming that your are retrieving your data in OnInit() which will usually be the JSON format.

Assign to some variable

```
onInit(){

 //Your service call

 this.data = Your JSON array;

}
```

in your

```
openPopup(index){

  this.data[index].columnname

  you can access... and show it in the table in frontend.
}
```

I have done something similar to yours.... shown table in modal.. I have used **ng2-bs3-modal**. Though I didn't give the exact answer. I have given the idea. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap modal. I have worte a component for you. You can use this.

**1. Install 'ngx-bootstrap/modal'**

> npm install 'ngx-bootstrap/modal'

**2. Import ngx-bootsrap in app.module**

**/// app.module.ts ///**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

import { TestComponent} from '.test.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ModalModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        TestComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**3. Create a Compenent
/// test.component.ts ///**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements {

    @ViewChild('autoShownModal') public autoShownModal: ModalDirective;
    public isModalShown: boolean = false;

    public showModal(): void {       
        this.isModalShown = true;        
    }

    public hideModal(): void {
        this.autoShownModal.hide();
    }

    public onHidden(): void {
        this.isModalShown = false;
    }
}
```

**4. Create Html file
/// test.component.html ///**

```
<button (click)="showModal()" >Open Popup</button>

<div *ngIf="isModalShown" [config]="{ show: true }" (onHidden)="onHidden()" bsModal #autoShownModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Title</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideModal()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Col1</th>
                        <th>Col2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>val 1</td>
                        <td>val 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>val 2</td>
                        <td>val 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```